# Get current object with the on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I update the specific input of the current line where the event "change" is called?

Here is my script:

```
$('#absence-table').on('change', '.from input, .to input',function() {
    var from   = $('.from input').val();
    var to     = $('.to input').val();

    if (from != "" && to != "")
    {
        d1 = getTimeStamp(from);
        d2 = getTimeStamp(to);

        if(d1 <= d2)
        {
            $('.result input').val(new Number(Math.round(d2 - d1)+1));
        }

        else
        {
            $('.result input').val(0);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="absence-table">
<tr>
    <th>Absence type</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>Days requested</th>
    <th>Morning</th>
    <th>Afternoon</th>
    <th colspan="2">Comment</th>
</tr>
<tr class="main-abs-line">
    <td>
        <select name="absence-type" class="input-small">
            <option value="t1">type1</option>
            <option value="t2">type2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="from"><input type="text" class="input-small" /></td>
    <td class="to"><input type="text" class="input-small" /></td>
    <td class="result"><div class="text-center"><input type="text" class="input-xsmall" /></div></td>
    <td class="morning"><div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
    <td class="afternoon"><div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
// some tr added by the append() method
```

Currently, only the result input of the first line is updated, the current result input is copied from the first. That's strange because the values from '.from input' and '.to input' are correct (values of the current line).

Normally I use $(this) to get the current object, but with the on() method I don't know the way to do it.

Comment: have you tried  `$(this)` ? you can use it with `.on()` too

Comment: @pXL I think he wants `#absence-table`, not the `input` that triggered the change.

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm assuming you have several groups of `.from`, `.to`, and `.result` and you are wanting to update the `.result` based on the associated `.from`. I'm guessing that the answer missed the mark for you, but if this is the case you would have to provide dom structure for us to help you.

Comment: Specifically, I need to get the current "tr", where there change() function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
$('#absence-table').on('change', '.from input, .to input',function() {
    $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var from   = $tr.find('.from input').val();
    var to     = $tr.find('.to input').val();

    if (from != "" && to != "")
    {
        d1 = getTimeStamp(from);
        d2 = getTimeStamp(to);

        if(d1 <= d2)
        {
            $tr.find('.result input').val(new Number(Math.round(d2 - d1)+1));
        }

        else
        {
            $tr.find('.result input').val(0);
        }
    }
});
```

This assumes you have several `tr`'s containing `.to`, `.from`, and `.result` and that when a `.to` or `.from` gets updated, you want the `.result` in the same `tr` to get updated.

Comment: Same as my script, only the result input of the first line is updated, the current result input is copied from the first.

Comment: did you use this in it's entirety? To me it sounds like you tried to modify and might have missed some of the `$tr.find()`'s

Comment: You're right. I have missed $tr.find() for the from and to vars. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a fiddle demonstrating that it is working on the correct row... I replaced the timestamp stuff to make it easier to see: http://jsfiddle.net/xg6rT/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.target` by passing event to function

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uPvnt/)**

```
function(event){
  alert(event.target.id);
```

Your code would be

```
$('#absence-table').on('change', '.from input, .to input',function(event) {
   alert(event.target.id);
   //your code
});
```

Comment: Probably this gaetanm. modify your function line to

    $('#absence-table').on('change', '.from input, .to   input',function(event) {

And see were you can go from there

Comment: @smerny depends on what sort of data you want to use, information about the clicked object or information about the click in this case. Doesn't matter for this simple requirement i'd say

Answer (score 2):

If (per your comments) you want the enclosing `tr` for whichever element triggered the `change` event, just use:

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Within the event handler, `this` corresponds to the triggering element, even if using delegated event handlers.